# How to load a pdf from a base64 string inside wkwebview

Tags: base64, wkwebview, swift4.2

i have tried all solutions but still i none works for me. Here is my code (i use swift 4.2).

Error is : found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value...
My data property is not empty.

```
var pdfic: WKWebView!

func pdfConv(id: String) -> WKWebView {
   let data: Data = Data(base64Encoded: id, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
   pdfic.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: 
   URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
   return pdfic!
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming id would be base64String    
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: id, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
    webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf-8", 
    baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
}
```

Check if it works.